# Why are these weird functions appearing which I using inner.HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have trying to show the JSON data on the HTML page but weirdly it doesn't show the JSON data but shows [this](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/901086715802959873/917707495332511774/unknown.png).

The same code works well if the `inner.HTML` line is removed and used `console.log` instead, [this](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/901086715802959873/917704744049467402/unknown.png) is the output if `console.log` is used instead of `inner.HTML`.

Code:

```js
pat = $.getJSON("../data/random/anime/pat/pat.json");

function randomObject(obj) {
    let arr = Object.values(obj);
    content = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = content;
}

randomObject(pat);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ASEAN API V2</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="content"></p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/api.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The JSON data:

```json
[
    {
        "gif": "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/901270821715210260/901270895446863912/neet-anime.png"
    },
    {
        "gif": "https://tenor.com/view/kanna-kamui-pat-head-pat-gif-12018819"
    },
    {
        "gif": "https://tenor.com/view/pat-head-gakuen-babysitters-kotarou-anime-cute-gif-17907437"
    },
    {
        "gif": "https://tenor.com/view/umaru-frown-happy-feeling-better-pat-gif-10947495"
    }
]
```

Comment: What do you think `$.getJSON` [returns with](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR)?

Comment: If you want to get the address from the arrays of the objects, the given console output is also not what you want. You need `arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)].gif;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce the same issue you're having, but the only thing I needed to change to get this working was to Stringify the object, so that I had it's content as a plain string.
This can then be applied to the HTML element

```
function randomObject(obj) {
    const arr = Object.values(obj); // Is this necessary? It works fine for me without, since the data is already an array
    const randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length); // As a variable to make it clearer what this is for
    // "Stringify" (Turn it into a string) first, then we can apply it to the HTML element's content as a plain string
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr[randomValue]);
}
```

Comment: Seeing the above answer, I see that your issue is more likely with the getJSON call not being awaited, and you're using its results prior to them being available.
My solution here assumes the data given above is available and just needed to be turned into a string for display. Otherwise it shows as [Object object]

Answer (score 1):

You should call randomObject like this: `randomObject(pat.responseJSON);` or

```
$.getJSON( "../data/random/anime/pat/pat.json", function( data ) {
  randomObject(data);
})
```

Comment: does it solve the problem?